# is it possible to load ajax on web page load

Tags: ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

im using panel collapse in bootstrap and has a parent category and child category

The parent was display for panel-title and the child categories was display on the panel-collapse to perform an ajax to load posts under child category

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Parent categories</a>
</h4>
 <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
   <a onclick(perform ajax event)><li>child categories</li>
 </div>
```

my problem was on page load all post was executed already. i just want only to show the post of the array 0 or to load an ajax on page load

Comment: Why not print them hidden and just show them on click?

Comment: no the requirements was to load the contents on page load...